# Data table not being populated

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, api, lightning-datatable

```
//Apex Class
public with sharing class PIIList {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<bhdata__PII_Fields__c> getPIIList(){
        return [select Id, bhdata__Field_API_Name__c,bhdata__Object_API_Name__c from bhdata__PII_Fields__c];
    }

}
```

//JS file

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire,api } from 'lwc';
import getPIIList from '@salesforce/apex/PIIList.getPIIList';

const columns=[{label: 'Id', fieldName: 'Id'},{label: 'Field API Name',fieldName: 'Field_API_Name__c'},{label:'Object API Name',fieldName:'Object_API_Name__c'}];

export default class PIIListCard extends LightningElement {
    @track columns = columns;

    @track error;
    @track data ;
    @wire(getPIIList) PII_Fields({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            this.data = data;

            console.log(data);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t'));
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
        }
    }

}
```

//html

```
<template>
    <h2> PII Table</h2>
    <lightning-datatable data={data} columns={columns} key-field="Id">
    </lightning-datatable>

</template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the namespace:

```
const columns=[{label: 'Id', fieldName: 'Id'},{label: 'Field API Name',fieldName: 'bhdata__Field_API_Name__c'},{label:'Object API Name',fieldName:'bhdata__Object_API_Name__c'}];
```

Comment: 'bhdata__Field_API_Name__c' I did

Comment: I did for the field Name

Comment: It works now thank you so much.